# How to avoid retyping or copy/paste a search term in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

In IE9, if the search engine one utilizes does not find what one was looking for, one has to retype the search in order to use a different search engine. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Flagged for closed. This isn't a question at all.

Comment: @APErebus I edited the question, as the core idea of the post is valid.

Answer (score 3):

You **do not** have to retype or copy and paste the search term. This is what you can do:

1. After searching using **Search Engine A**, click the `magnifying glass` icon in the address bar. The search suggestions drop-down will appear.

   [image: magnifying glass]
2. **Double click** on the icon for **Search Engine B** at the bottom of the drop-down.

   [image: screenshot]
3. ...

   [image: search engine b]
4. Profit!

> Note: this works even if you have drifted away from a search engine's website, as Internet Explorer will remember your most recent search from the address bar.